# How do I close a project in Jira?

Tags: project-management, bug-tracking, jira, jira-plugin

There are a few tasks still open in the backlog, but we're done with the project and I would like to close it.  How do I do that?

Comment: Here's the process we use for closing/archiving unused projects: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3696798/how-to-archive-projects-in-jira-so-they-would-disappear-from-projects-picker/7116196#7116196](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3696798/how-to-archive-projects-in-jira-so-they-would-disappear-from-projects-picker/7116196#7116196)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Create permission scheme "Closed Project", which prohibits editing and creating issues. This way, you don't have to modify the roles and you can easily "reopen" the project by switching the permission scheme.